# Correct way to use hook_menu_alter

Tags: 7, routes

What is the correct way of using hook_menu_later.

I did this in my module to redirect (see also [redirect in hook_init makes body text disappear](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125980/redirect-in-hook-init-makes-body-text-disappear/125981#125981)):

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['page callback'] = 'citykidz_node_page_view';
}

function MYMODULE_node_page_view($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'event') {
    if ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_event_date')) {
      $date = date_create($items[0]['value']);
      drupal_goto('news/events/day/' . date_format($date, 'Y-m-d'));
    }
  }
  else {
    return node_page_view($node);
  }
}
```

And this got me wondering: what if other modules are also overriding hook_menu_alter and setting their own page callbacks on 'node/%node'? Or even on access or whatever. This is the standard Drupal way of doing things, but surely it will lead to problems (that can be hard to detect). I see there is a module [Chain Menu Access API](https://www.drupal.org/project/chain_menu_access) that addresses this. Has anyone had success using this module? And has this issue been addressed in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two modules are altering the same menu item / form / page etc, last one will "win".

If you need some control over this, and are expecting collisions, you need to implement [`hook_module_implements_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7):

> This hook is invoked during module_implements(). A module may implement this hook in order to reorder the implementing modules, which are otherwise ordered by the module's system weight.

Do your best to have your hook fire last, and if menu item you are altering does not look like the one you are expecting (it was altered already), write a warning message to watchdog.

Comment: That is excellent advice, especially in the case of a page callback where I want my module's code to run. But could it be possible that correct execution of the code depends on multiple module's code to run, especially in the case of the 'access callback'?

Comment: @J.Reynolds Access callbacks are different, they are not altering single object, they are just adding "yes / no / no change" entries to access array. They are *designed* to be used by many modules simultaneously, so should not create any problems.

Comment: Other modules can also execute `hook_module_implements_alter()` and put their `hook_menu_alter` on top ;)

Comment: @milkovsky yes, they can. As usual, simple solution is not to install two conflicting software (here: modules) on one system.

Comment: After thinking about it some more I am finding myself unconvinced. What if I install Revisioning module and my own module. My module runs later than Revisioning. I implement hook_menu_alter for nodes at revision edit path (node/%/revision/%/edit I think). I only want to allow person to edit revision if he has certain userpoints. Must I now re-implement Revisioning's complex set of permissions also? I must return either TRUE or FALSE. Hence I will have to chain onto Revisioning's own access calback, and if it return TRUE then do I do my own module's check on top of that.

Comment: @J.Reynolds In that case you can call revisioning's callback from your callback if needed, you know.

Comment: The way I understand it Revisioning's own alter hooks will also run. And if I implement hook_menu_alter on the page callback, then I explicitly want to exclude Revisioning's page callback in favour of mine. But I still want Revisioning's access callback to run in addition to mine, else I will have to re-implement it and I break modularity. To me this seems like an unresolved cross cutting concern.

Comment: @Molot I agree with you, thanks for clearing that up. I will investigate Chain Menu Access API and try and use that.

Comment: @J.Reynolds This site is not a forum. If you want to ask more specific question, ask it as a question. If you want to continue discussion here, I will not participate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16275/discussion-between-j-reynolds-and-molot).