# hook_menu_alter with Organic Groups

Tags: 7, routes, hooks, organic-groups

I want to change the menu button on my main nav bar depending if the user is or isn't a member of a group.

I need one button to 'register' if the user isn't part of a group and **that same button** changes to 'add post' if he/she is.

I do not know what to put in the array. Do I put an IF statement similar to "[Correct way to use hook_menu_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125983)"?

```
   function change_menu_menu_alter(&$items) {
     $items['/node/[nid]'] = array(
       'access callback' => 'change_menu_custom_menu_access_callback',
       'access arguments' => array(1),
       // **I don't know what goes here!!!**
     );
       return $items;
   }
   function change_menu_custom_menu_access_callback($gid) {
     return og_is_member('node', $gid);
   }
```

**EDIT**: I do not have gid in my url as I am using pathauto to use [node:content-type]/[node:title] on my URL which is why I don't think the current answer works on my website.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved a similar problem with the `hook_menu()` and the use of '`title callback`' and `'page callback'`

```
function YOUR_MODULE_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['link'] = array(
        'title' => 'test',
        'description' => t('Just a test'),
        'title callback' => 'change_title_link',
        'title arguments' => array(1),
        'page callback' => 'go_to_place',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
        'expanded' => TRUE,
        'weight' => 100,
        'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
        'options' => array('attributes' => array('class' => array('perfil-usuario'))),
        ); 

    return $items;
}
```

In this function you can change the link title

```
function change_title_link($gid) {
  if(og_is_member('node', $gid)) {
    return 'Post';
  }
  else {
    return 'Register';  
  }
}
```

Here you can redirect to the desire url

```
function go_to_place($gid) {
  if(og_is_member('node', $gid)) {
    drupal_goto('/someplace/post');
  }
  else {
    drupal_goto('/someplace/register');
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! makes perfect sense apart from 3 questions I have: 1) What does the `options' => array('attributes' => array('class' => array('perfil-usuario'))), ); ` mean? 2) what does `array(1)` mean after title arguments and page arguments? 3) Why is there first an `items array()` followed by an `items ['links'] array`? Thanks

Comment: @ldvt5 I don't have time at this moment you can read more at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7 for 1 and 2, and for 3 you can read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I do understand your answer better now - but (as you can see from my edit) should it still work with [node:content-type]/[node:title] in the URL?